# Copying VMware Fusion virtual Windows 7 machine to a bootcamp partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

Is it possible to copy my virtual disk contents to my Bootcamp partition and use bootcamp from there. I know you can use a bootcamp partition as a virtual machine, if you already have Windows on a bootcamp partition, but how about vice-versa.

This is a Windows 7 virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many applications have you installed in you Windows 7 virtual machine? If it's not too many, you would be much better off creating a fresh install of Windows 7 using the Boot Camp Assistant, and then using [Windows Easy Transfer](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/windows-easy-transfer.aspx) to transfer your data. Use it first in your VMware installation to export your data to a USB external hard drive. Then, once you've installed your Boot Camp partition and reinstalled your applications, use Windows Easy Transfer to import your data from the USB external. [Here's an MSDN video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/NicFill/The-Complete-Guide-to-Windows-Easy-Transfer/) that I didn't watch but may be useful.

[image: Windows Easy Transfer]

I say this because it's unreliable to clone a Windows installation for use on another computer. The VMware virtual machine is considered to be *another computer* in this case compared to your Mac since it uses some virtual hardware in Windows (e.g. graphics chip).

Comment: Guess i'll have to make do with that.