# Make VirtualBox VM bootable in Boot Camp

Tags: macos, virtualbox, boot-camp

I currently have Windows 7 installed in VirtualBox on Mac OS X 10.6 and I was wondering if there is any way to make that image bootable via Boot Camp. I already have my disk partitioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought this was a duplicate. In any case, I have never used VirtualBox, but the other day [someone asked about doing this for VMware Fusion](https://superuser.com/questions/95398/copying-vmware-fusion-virtual-windows-7-machine-to-a-bootcamp-partition). I think my advice there might be useful, where you install a fresh copy of Windows 7 on the Boot Camp partition, then use the Windows Easy Transfer program to transfer your files and settings.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use a free microsoft tool to zip up an installation and make it portable so that we could use it for "imaging" (like cloning) other systems.  I imagine that you could do the same with your system.  One tool that we used was Norton Ghost, but I would recommend looking for free alternatives.